Why was this question deleted by the community bot?
Here is the question, for those who have access to it: Paired test on nominal data in a non-squared contingency table in R
This question was closed on the grounds of lacking enough details, which is what probably prompted its deletion. It was not a question from a deleted user (so the problem is different from Why was this on-topic question deleted?), and it had one answer with three upvotes.
I noticed it has been deleted because I was the person who wrote the upvoted answer, and I lost some reputation over the thread deletion. This is disappointing because I put some work in answering it.
Maybe I'm wrong, but in the case of this particular question, it was so specific that I don't think it would be possible to write a canonical question/answer as a remedy to the thread deletion, as @Glen_b suggested once.
If this is a normal behavior from the community bot, what strategy can I use in the future to decide what questions to answer, and ensure my answers won't be deleted like that?

Edit: The question has been undeleted (thanks @whuber). I'm not sure if the community bot will repeat this action in the future, but if this happen again I'll just consider reposting an improved version of the question myself and answer it as suggested by @mkt, though this may obviously require some additional work and time.
For those interested, I just found that the complete rules for automated deletion are exposed here. Different rules for automated deletion seem to apply to migrated questions (compared to non-migrated questions), which may be good to know.

It was migrated here from StackOverflow, and then closed. This led to a rejection (see below) and automatic deletion.

What is migration and how does it work? says

A question will be considered rejected by the target community after
it has already been migrated if, on the target site, one of the
following things happen before the migration stub on the origin site
is deleted:

The question gets closed for any reason other than as a duplicate (unless the migration was to the site's per-site meta)
The question gets deleted (unless it was closed as a duplicate or merged before being deleted)

When a question which was already migrated gets rejected later, the
entire process of the migration is reversed, except the original
question will remain closed as off-topic. All the answers are returned
to the origin site and undeleted, and are subsequently deleted on the
target site*. Also, the rejected question on the target site will be
locked, then automatically deleted 30 days later by a weekly script.

I haven't read the thread carefully, but if there is a good question at its core, I think it would be reasonable to post a new, valid question (perhaps linking to the deleted one) and answer it. It doesn't need to be a big, broad 'canonical' thread to justify doing that.

Oof. Thanks for the explanation. If this is really what happened (I wait a bit to see if others can confirm this), then I think that now I won't invest too much time answering migrated questions, unless they got a ton of upvotes from CV users, which should mitigate the risk of seeing them closed.

BTW, I think I don't quite understand "All the answers are returned to the origin site and undeleted, and are subsequently deleted on the target site", as I find no trace of this thread on stackoverflow (the link "This post was returned to Stack Overflow. " points to a "Page not found" error).

@J-J-J That's because I think this thread was closed here before the 'migration stub on the origin site is deleted' (I don't know how long this takes though). I think it just gets deleted when this happens, not sent back.

@J-J-J This doesn't seem common, so I wouldn't hold off on answering just because of this. Especially since you can always post as a new question & answer.

Thanks for all the explanations and suggestion. The question has been undeleted, and I edited my question above accordingly. I'm wondering if the current bot behavior is consistent with the general rules for the deletion of closed questions, but maybe this is material for another discussion, broader than the case of this specific question.

OK, I just found the page listing the complete current rules: https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/auto-deleted-questions. This is in fact expected that the bot behavior is different for migrated questions, and it is a rule apparently common to all stackexchange websites. So that's more a discussion for https://meta.stackexchange.com.

@J-J-J Sure thing! And yeah, that auto-deleted questions page is the first link in my answer :) Probably should have quoted the relevant text.

Sorry for the redundant comment then, I don't know why I completely missed this link. Next time I'll read much more carefully!

@J-J-J No problem at all. Glad it's sorted.
