Question with 4 upvotes, answers, and granted bounty was deleted by a bot
I did a question in MSE that got migrated to CrossValidated, where the question got 4 upvotes, got a few interesting answers, and even I granted a bounty to one of them.
The question keep growing as I tried to answer it based on the comments and aswers I received, and it got closed.
Today I was traying to share it with someone else more experienced to see if my demonstrations where right, but I found it was deleted by a bot, so nobody else can see it, neither the interesting answers I received (length is not an argument for deletion as far I know).
I would like to undelete it but in CrossValidated I don't even have enough stats to vote (I don't see the undelete vote option).
Hope you could help me to undelete it: How to make two perfectly negatively correlated growing Geometric Brownian Motion (GBM) series? (Impossibility)

It had turned into a monograph, of a length unsuitable for any SE site.  A site moderator has kindly undeleted it for your convenience, but expect it to get deleted again soon.

This is the same issue as https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6730/. Migrated questions get automatically deleted when they are closed. We can discuss it, but we can not do much about it as this is a policy for the entire site and not something related to this sub-stack specifically. The only solution is to make the question focused such that it can be opened. That's not bad advice in any case. The question has the staggering size of almost 30k characters, which is equivalent to the size of several scientific research papers. It should be possible to reduce it to 1k characters.

@SextusEmpiricus  I cannot edit it since it gives a message that the "post is locked" so is not much what I can to do for improve it (I was thinking to move demonstration to the answers), and also if deleted I lose the answer you gave. So now I am in a limbo where there is nothing I can do :(

It is probably locked because it is returned to the ath site

Please do mention the useful commentary made by Sycorax in Ten Fold.

@Joako This might be a technical problem. Currently the system mentions "This post was returned to Mathematics Stack Exchange". But the link  https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4983395/ doesn't work.

If I remember it takes few days for the closed question to return to the parent site and add to that the question was deleted by the system. Not an easy situation. @SextusEmpiricus

Right click on the equations and select display mathjax. This gives you the typesetting for each equation without editing.

In case the question is automatically deleted again, it is available with its answers on Internet Archive, at https://web.archive.org/web/20241206152253/https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/655735/how-to-make-two-perfectly-negatively-correlated-growing-geometric-brownian-motio. But this is certainly a good idea to follow Dave's recommendation below.

Please note that one of our elected diamond moderators has graciously unlocked the post for you to copy the content into a text file that you save on your computer. You can then draw on your existing content to ask multiple related questions. I suggest copying the content to your computer soon.

My recommendation is to break your inquiries into multiple related questions where the questions and answers are not journal articles. We like good questions. You are unlikely to face any kind of penalty from posting multiple good questions.

I cannot edit it now so I cannot even take the equations out this because the post is locked. This is why I am sking for help.

CV mods couldn't do anything here (could they?) as it was migrated back to Maths and locked, that is kind of in a phantom zone. If you wish, you can ask this at Meta SE.

@Joako If you click the edit history, you can access some, even if not all, of the $\LaTeX$.

Here is a direct link to the source obtained via the edit history https://stats.stackexchange.com/revisions/2c94f5b5-682c-452b-b624-c51bd7593b30/view-source

@SextusEmpiricus That's everything, isn't it? That's exactly what Joako would want to save in Notepad and use to post shorter questions, right?

I unlocked the post for now, but please follow the advice from others here, just copy the post to some private file, and work on making multiple nes, more focused and shorter posts

@kjetilbhalvorsen Thanks you very much. I have edited to its original length. I hope this avoid its deletion so I can kept the comments also.

@Joajo As mentioned in a previous comment, the whole thread has been duplicated on Internet Archive. So in the worst case scenario where it's automatically deleted again, you'll be able to retrieve the question, answers, and comments there: https://web.archive.org/web/20241207100700/https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/655735/how-to-make-two-perfectly-negatively-correlated-growing-geometric-brownian-motio . The page is just a bit slow to load.

The thread has been re-opened. The excellent advice in this answer  has been completely ignored. It's unfortunate that various actions led to the OP losing access to their work temporarily -- although it would have been prudent to keep a copy -- but that seems to have been solved. Meanwhile, we are back where we were some time ago with a question so long that it spills into an answer. What next: blog-like posts as new threads?

@NickCox I see where Joako might be coming from. I have a similar monster here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/291367/ an accumulation of several edits and the post gets bigger while you don't want to cut out old parts. That was my 31-st answer here and I have learned a lot now. I guess that my style of answers is often from a perspective of a novice and I can get to an intuitive explanation at a low level because I am at that level. However the downside is that I may not understand the topic good enough. Nowadays, if I get into a struggle with my own thoughts, then I just delete it.

@SextusEmpiricus  I don't see your moderately long answer a few years back as having any bearing on the question of why the thread in question has been re-opened. Any active member here has sometimes answered at some length. I can guess only that it arises out of sympathy and embarrassment at the way the question was handled by SE.

@NickCox I revised the answer after making my comment. It used to be longer https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/291367/revisions

You’re strengthening the point that very long length isn’t invariably, or even usually, a good thing.

@NickCox Yes sure. The old answer and me correcting it makes the point that this verbose stuff isn't good. But, the newer me has less problems in deleting big parts of an answer and cutting down large pieces of work, just to make it all more digestible. But I still understand the older me and why he didn't wanted to delete the superfluous parts in a question. And I relate it to Joako's question where he invested some time and got strangled in an overcooked blob of entangled spaghetti because he threw too much into a small pan with not enough water. I don't like to throw away food.
